# Неизвестная ошибка EOF

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня ошибка синтаксиса: непредвиденое ЕОФ во время парсинга.
Как это исправить?

```
    import telebot
import configure
from telebot import types

client = telebot.TeleBot(configure.conf['token'])


@client.message_handler(commands = ['get_info', 'info'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'ДА', callback_data = 'yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'НЕТ', callback_data = 'no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Желаете узнать немного о себе?',
        reply_markup = markup_inline
    )
@client.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_id = types.KeyboardButton('МОЙ ID')
        item_username = types.KeyboardButton('МОЙ НИК')

        markup_reply.add(item_id, item_username)
        client.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нажмите на одну из кнопок',
            reply_markup = markup_reply
            )

    elif call.data == 'no':
        pass

def usename_info(message):
    if message.text == "МОЙ ID":
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ID : {message.from_user.id}')
    elif message.text == "МОЙ НИК":
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ник : {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}')
        client.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас декоратор  `@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])`не оборачивает функцию `usename_info(message)`, а находится непонятно где

Должно быть так:

```
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def usename_info(message):
        if message.text == "МОЙ ID":
            client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ID : {message.from_user.id}')
        elif message.text == "МОЙ НИК":
            client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш ник : {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}')
            client.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```